# Additional parameters for Storage file upload to secure acces - Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I am uploading file to my Firebase storage with this code:

```
storageRef.child('docs/docName').put(file, metadata);
```

where file is a js File document and metadata looks like:

```
{
  customMetadata: {
    test: "check"
  }
}
```

It is necessary for me from security reasonsve defined:

```
 match /docs/{doc} {
        allow read, write: if request.resource.metadata.test == 'check';
    }
```

But this is not working. Don't know why :/

When I change rules to be:

```
 match /docs/{doc} {
        allow read, write: if true;
    }
```

Then the file is uploaded properly.

I have tried also using params according to documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/rules-conditions)

```
storageRef.child('docs/docName?test="check"').put(file, metadata);
```

With rules:

```
 match /docs/{doc} {
        allow read, write: if request.params.test == 'check';
    }
```

But it is not working.

The most funniest thing is that:

```
 match /docs/{doc} {
        allow read, write: if request.resource == null;
    }
```

and

match /docs/{doc} {
allow read, write: if request.resource != null;
}

Are both not working like request.resource is not available...

How can I send some additional parameter for security reasons?